# What resolution will be able to show visible changes on a parcel of farm land?

Tags: remote-sensing, satellite, resolution

What resolution will be adequate (5m, 2.5m, etc) to show visible changes on a parcel of farm land? Each plot is typically the size of two football pitches.

Details to detect:

a) has the farm land been cleared of bush/ over growth

b) have rows of planting ridges appeared

c) have rows of planting ridges shown signs of change: size, colour, etc

**Background**

1) we need to track farming activity for given parcels of farm land

2) we have boundary coordinates for each of the farm land above

3) we need to see evidence of farming activity on each allocated parcel of land

4) Our project is in the Sub-Saharan region

**My Approach:**

1) Collate database of farm-plots boundaries

2) upload set of plot boundaries to a satellite image provider on a weekly (or daily) schedule

3) download latest images from the satellite image provider, then run an image compare algorithm to circle very distinct areas of change (if any)

Is there a simpler approach to achieve the same outlined above?

Comment: @polygeo i have edited the question to reflect what i really need. the rest is provided as background

Comment: I think this is too broad on a number of counts.  You seem to be asking for a project review which is too broad for focussed Q&A.  You then seem to be asking "What resolution will be adequate"?, "Are there Satellite imaging Services"?, and "Is there a simpler approach"? i.e. multiple questions.  As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: @PolyGeo I have edited as you directed kindly remove from "on hold". Thanks

Comment: I'll re-open this but I suspect that "adequate resolution" may invite opinions making it problematic on different grounds.

Comment: Depends on what you call "visible". Is a ant on a leaf visible for you? What is the smallest element you want to be able to see on your plot? This question is too boad and depends on subjective opinions thus will probably be closed again.

Comment: Why did you delete all those information from your question? There might be interesting facts within that affect the answers quality.

Comment: @HimBromBeere following advice from PolyGeo... I will returen the info

Comment: It also depends on what "change" means in your case.  If you refer to crop type for the entire parcel as a whole maybe you should be more focused on the spectral resolution that fits your needs (for example vegetation presence and health is more easily estimated if you have infrared data). Also,  please provide an aproximation for plot area in square meters or something, since 'the size of two football pitches' can mean a lot of things (soccer or american football field? etc).

Comment: @Mihnea the project needs to show "visible evidence of farming activity". Infrared would not be unacceptable, because the project managers would find it difficult to make a case of inactivity with infrared images

Comment: Your question seems to have largely returned to being about asking for a project/methodology review.  You may want to consider the GIS Chat Room as an alternative way to get the feedback that you seek.

Answer (score 2):

As PolyGeo mentioned in his comment, your question is too broad. There are plenty of satellite images with high spatial resolution including QuickBird, Ikonos, WorldView-1 and WorldView-2 (spatial resolution of 0.46 m), and you can [check sample image of WorldView-2](http://www.satimagingcorp.com/gallery/worldview-2/worldview-2-sydney-australia-olympic-center/), WorldView-3 now provide data at 0.31 m resolution. Answering this question will not be easy, as all the above data has excellent resolution, but it depends on the objective of your research, budget, and temporal resolution (frequency of the sensor to visit the same area again). It is difficult to recommend which is the best because it depends on you. You can check [this link](http://www.satimagingcorp.com/) which has plenty of sample images of different sensors and sensor information. Then you can decide which is best suitable for you.

Comment: I had already spoken with the people @ www.satimagingcorp.com. was hoping for other options. Thanks